# Add class to custom component angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a `<myComponent ></myComponent>` and I want give class to myComponent?

```
This doesnt worked `<myComponent class="my-class"></myComponent>`
```

How can  I do that?

Comment: what is the issue you are getting? are you trying to apply style from class within the content of component?

Comment: Yes @MadhuRanjan, I want give for example border color,width etc. to my control as one control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.my-class')
  isMyClass:boolean = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,and where to use  **isMyClass** property ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question. `isMyClass` is just a name I chose. The name doesn't matter. `'class.my-class'` defines what class should be added or removed. The value of the property where `@HostBinding()` is prepended is used to determine if the class should be added or removed (`true`/`false`). The only thin where the name of `isMyClass` is relevent, is when you want to change the value like `this.isMyClass = false;`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean? What do you try to accomplish? What is not working with the code in your question?

Comment: Now it's works,formerly 'my-class' writenn in MyComponent's syleUrl's file.
I replace it in styes.css (included in head) ,and everything is ok.

I want understand your answer.

Comment: The code in my answer just adds `my-class` to the host element of the `MyComponent` component. You can now style it from the parent elements `styleUrls: ['parent.css']` using `:host my-component.my-class { ... }` or from `MyComponent`s `styleUrls: [my-component.css']` using `:host-context(.my-class) { ... }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124407/discussion-between-emanuel07-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 4):

Don't think that will work but there are easy workarounds:

**If you want to style the placement/color etc of your component:**

Best workaround is to place your `<myComponent></myComponent>` inside a `<div>` and apply the class to that `div`

**If you want to style the contents of your component:**

adding `styleUrls` in your `Component` and styling your content with a `css` file

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@Input** for your component and set external class in any place.

Example:

```
<myComponent [styleClass]="'my-class'"></myComponent>>
```

Your component

/my-component.component.ts

```
...
@Input() styleClass: string; 
...
```

/my-component.component.html

```
   <div [class]="styleClass" ngClass="my-component__container any-other-class">
Component works!
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can using **host** method

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'COMPONENT NAME',
    templateUrl: 'COMPONENT URL',
    host: {
        '[class.CLASS NAME]': 'VARIABLE NAME'
    }
})

export class componentName{
}
```